# ReplayKit and discardRecordingWithHandler

Tags: ios, replaykit

Just me or does `discardRecordingWithHandler:` in ReplayKit not work? At all. Has anyone ever been able to discard a recording? What I see is, the handler is never called. The recording is never discarded.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issues with discardRecord functionality and found an introductory tutorial here:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-9-an-introduction-to-replaykit--cms-25458

And copying the points related to `discardRecordingWithHandler:` for future reference:

- Note that this method **can only be called successfully once a recording has finished**. If you call this method while a recording is in-progress, no error is thrown, but no recording data is discarded either.
- Only one recording can be stored at any one time per app. As soon as you start a new recording, if a previous recording exists it will be discarded automatically and no longer available.
- Discard recordings as soon as possible. To ensure that a device's
  local storage doesn't remain filled with unnecessary video data,
  discard recordings as soon as you know that the user won't or can't
  access their recording at a later point.

Hope this helps...